# how to replace string in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have predefined url from server and want to replace the string in flutter dart.

For example as follow. I have no idea what is the route it is but I know that if I found ${track_id}, replace with real value. Same for ${artist_id} and ${album_id} and return the real url.

[https://thitsarparami.org/artist/${artist_id}/album/${album_id}/track/${track_id}](https://thitsarparami.org/artist/$%7Bartist_id%7D/album/$%7Balbum_id%7D/track/$%7Btrack_id%7D)
[https://thitsarparami.org/${artist_id}/${album_id}/${track_id}](https://thitsarparami.org/$%7Bartist_id%7D/$%7Balbum_id%7D/$%7Btrack_id%7D)

May I know how to replace dynamically.

Comment: You could use [String.replaceAll](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/replaceAll.html) to replace all occurrences and [String.replaceFirst](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/replaceFirst.html) to replace only the first result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below example,

```
String refineUrl(String url) {

  if(url.contains("${album_id}")) {
    url = url.replaceAll("${album_id}", "<realAlbumId>");
  }
  // repeat the above check for all the dynamic values


  return url;
}

String url = "https://thitsarparami.org/artist/${artist_id}/album/${album_id}/track/${track_id}";

url = refineUrl(url);
```

Alternatively, you can send the `albumId` and other values through the function parameter.